# ORA-22806 (not an object or REF) on Join to a view

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql, view

Here is a fairly simple query that is throwing this error:

```
SELECT RR.REQUEST_ID
FROM CCS_REQUEST_RESPONSE RR 
INNER JOIN VW_STUDENT_CURRENT_AND_HIST VW
ON RR.STUDENTID = VW.STUDENT_NUMBER
```

This only happens when joining to the view.
The view is a simple union all of 2 identical tables. 
When I substitute a single table instead of the view in the above query, it works fine.

So,

```
SELECT RR.REQUEST_ID
FROM CCS_REQUEST_RESPONSE RR 
INNER JOIN HISTORICAL_STUDENTS VW
ON RR.STUDENTID = VW.STUDENT_NUMBER
```

Works just fine.

And here is the view:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "VW_STUDENT_CURRENT_AND_HIST" ("STUDENT_NUMBER") AS 
  SELECT "STUDENT_NUMBER"
    FROM HISTORICAL_STUDENTS
UNION ALL
  SELECT "STUDENT_NUMBER"
      FROM CURRENT_YEAR_STUDENTS;
```

Interesting thing is that this used to work and suddenly stopped. 
Any ideas?

Comment: couldn't hurt to CAST student_number to a number as in  SELECT CAST(STUDENT_NUMBER AS NUMBER(9)) AS STUDENT_NUMBER

Comment: Please describe all the tables using `DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

The two tables in the view, though identical in respect to field names and definitions had a different field order.

I dropped and recreated one of the tables using the same DDL as the other and it's now working.

I don't know *why* that would be a problem.

Comment: *"I don't know why that would be a problem"* It's a problem because the subqueries in a UNION must have projections which match in number of and **datatypes** of  columns. I'm guessing that your columns have different datatypes, consequently the order of columns (not fields) must be the same in both projections.